# Finding β for binomial experiment

Tags: binomial-distribution, statistical-power, type-i-and-ii-errors

> $X\sim \text{Binomial}(5,P)$
>
> Rejection region $X ≤1$
>
> $H_\text{null}: P=0.6$
>   $H_\text{alt}:  P<0.6$
>
> Find $β$ at $P= 0.3$

I understand that ($β$ = not in the rejection region/H alt. is true). But how 
    do I find $β$ for $P$ at $0.3$?

Comment: p=0.3 is the alternative value that you should be using for the calculation: β = not in the rejection region/H alt. is true

Comment: Your statement "β = not in the rejection region/H alt. is true" is not correct. The thing on the LHS of the equality is a probability, the thing on the right hand side is an event. You should either equate two probabilities or two events.

Comment: 1. What values of $X$ correspond to "X not in the rejection region"? 2. If $P=0.3$ what's the probability of that event?